# Tricks like Loaded Questions

Tags: reference-request

I'm asking as a dilettante and greenhorn, so am interested in applied, informal, practical aids or resources (and not abstract, formal, esoteric papers).

1. Is there a (catholic/general) term that envelops/oversees tricks like a loaded question?
2. What are some resources or references that satisfy the above criteria and explain these devices?

I ask in the interest of enlightenment and protection against sudden hostile attacks with these artifices.

Answer (score 1):

The most approachable resource I've found is:

https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/

It's not 100% rigorously correct in all cases, but it provides a simple place to start learning.

For more detail, you can always read through wikipedia which is maintained well and is well referenced for more detail:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies